# productivity using calculus

Tags: calculus

I am having a tough time with this problem and I am looking for someone who can walk me through the problem.

The productivity of a certain country is given by $Q(K,L)=90K^{1/3} L^{2/3}$ units, where $K$ is the capital expenditure in units of 1 million and $L$ is the size of the labor force in thousands of worker-hours. The capital expenditure is currently 4.98 billion dollars and the labor level is 5,478,000 worker-hours. If productivity is desired to be increased by 1,100 units and capital expenditures are to be increased by 19 million dollars, what change should be made to the labor force? Round your answer to the nearest worker-hour.

I know that I need to integrate with respect to x and y and then multiply them by the changes in x and the change in q but everytime i do it i get it wrong.

i got $1100=(30y^{2/3})/x^{2/3}\times.019+ \left( 60x^{1/3}/y^{1/3} \right)$ and i got $-8557.45$ and that's wrong no matter how i round it.

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving out $dy$ and $dx$.

$$dQ=30k^{-1/3}L^{2/3}dK+60K^{1/3}L^{-1/3}dL$$

If I understand your units correctly I get $dL=8.475$ which would translate to 8475 additional workers.